# Не работают действия на кнопку

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Почему не выводится сообщение при нажатии на кнопку `#knopka_OK`?

```
function form_input() {
    html = '';
    html += '<button id="knopka_OK">Запись хода</button>';

    $(html).appendTo('#body')
    $('#knopka_OK').hide()
    $('#qwe').click(function () {
        form_input();
    })
    $('#qwe').click(function () {
        $(this).unbind('click');
    })
    $('#knopka_OK').click(function () {
        alert('fgtrhfyh');
    })
}
```

Comment: код на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) выложите плиз -- будем помогать, а так...

Comment: @MikeVin, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FxhEh/1/

Comment: ну а где что? где вызывается `form_input()`? она нигде не запускается, соответственно никаких обработчиков не будет повешено на кнопку...

Comment: Начнём из сокращения вашего кода.

    function form_input() {    
        $('<button id="knopka_OK">Запись хода</button>').appendTo('#body')
        $('#knopka_OK').hide().click(function(){
            alert('fgtrhfyh');
        })
    }

Теперь обьясните, где и как вы нажимаете на кнопку или имитируете нажатие на неё и что работает не так?

Answer (score 1):

Сообщение не выводится потому что вы только добавляете **описание** действия на событие click. Чтобы имитировать действие клик попробуйте

`$('#knopka_OK').trigger('click');`

А вообще, если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то лучше сделать вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/5WBmX/